# Replace C++ pointer field access symbol to a period, using sed

Tags: sed, replace

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of `->` with `.`. I've tried the following:

```
sed -i s/->/./g licensewizard.cpp
```

But this gives me an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command
```

I'm not sure what's wrong since neither `-` nor `>` need to be escaped if I'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to single quote your sed commands so that the shell wont try to interpret any of the chars.  In this particular instance, your shell was interpreting the `>` character to attempt a redirection.

```
sed -i 's/->/./g' licensewizard.cpp
```

Comment: Good call. I've had to use double-quotes, but it means the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrej careful, double and single quotes do *not* mean the same thing to the shell.  The shell will still attempt to expand `$` and anything escaped like `\x`.  *Always* use single quotes to surround inline commands who have syntax different from the shell; like `sed` or `awk` as examples.

Comment: Doesn't work with single quotes, but I'm on Windows. Thanks for the tip though.